# PDP GD Skewing images

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, distortion

Is it possible with PHP GD to skew/distort images on both sides ?
I already check other question/solution but I really don't understand how to move all the corners of the image.
What I need is transform a flat image to a distort image moving all 4 corners, something like if you use Adobe Photoshop transform distortion function that allows to move single corner to a new position.
Is it possible ?
Many thanks in advance.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the help of [the QB extension](http://www.php-qb.net/index.php/2-uncategorised/24-image-distortion).

In theory, it's possible to accomplish the same thing using just the built-in GD functions. It'd be agonizingly slow though.